# Botón permanezca cambiado de color al ser usado

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas tardes quisiera que al haber apretado un botón de los 14 que tengo este permanezca de otro color ya que tienen que ser usados uno por día y así no genere confusión ya que quedara marcado los ya utilizados.

Este es mi Codigo activity de los botones:

```
package com.mic.misprimerospasosenlasantidad;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

public class Semanav1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageView back;
Button bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5,bt6,bt7,bt8,bt9,bt10,bt11,bt12,bt13,bt14;
TextView tv_prin;

FloatingActionButton mas, menos;
private int ValorTexto = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_semanav1);
    back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backanw);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    mas=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btncm);
    menos=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btncmn);

    String text1=" example";




    tv_prin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_prin);
    tv_prin.setText(text1);

    if (ValorTexto == 0){
        ValorTexto = 20;
        tv_prin.setTextSize(ValorTexto);
    }
    mas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ValorTexto == 0){
                ValorTexto = 20;
            }
            if (ValorTexto < 50){
                ValorTexto = ValorTexto + 2;
                tv_prin.setTextSize(ValorTexto);
            }
        }
    });
    menos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ValorTexto == 0){
                ValorTexto = 20;
            }
            if (ValorTexto > 10){
                ValorTexto = ValorTexto - 2;
                tv_prin.setTextSize(ValorTexto);
            }
        }
    });

    bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    bt2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    bt3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    bt4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    bt5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    bt6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    bt7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    bt8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    bt9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    bt10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn10);
    bt11=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn11);
    bt12=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn12);
    bt13=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn13);
    bt14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn14);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt2.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt3.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt4.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt5.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt6.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt7.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt8.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt9.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt10.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt11.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt12.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt13.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt14.setOnClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v){

    TextView tvnamed = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvnamed);


    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent1.putExtra("1",1);
            startActivity(intent1);

            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent2.putExtra("1",2);
            startActivity(intent2);

            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent3.putExtra("1",3);
            startActivity(intent3);

            break;


        case R.id.btn4:

                 Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
                 intent4.putExtra("1",4);
                    startActivity(intent4);

                            break;



        case R.id.btn5:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent5.putExtra("1",5);
            startActivity(intent5);

            break;
        case R.id.btn6:
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent6.putExtra("1",6);
            startActivity(intent6);

            break;
        case R.id.btn7:
            Intent intent7 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent7.putExtra("1",7);
            startActivity(intent7);

            break;
        case R.id.btn8:
            Intent intent8 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent8.putExtra("1",8);
            startActivity(intent8);

            break;
        case R.id.btn9:
            Intent intent9 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent9.putExtra("1",9);
            startActivity(intent9);

            break;
        case R.id.btn10:
            Intent intent10 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent10.putExtra("1",10);
            startActivity(intent10);

            break;
        case R.id.btn11:
            Intent intent11 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent11.putExtra("1",11);
            startActivity(intent11);

            break;
        case R.id.btn12:
            Intent intent12 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent12.putExtra("1",12);
            startActivity(intent12);

            break;
        case R.id.btn13:
            Intent intent13 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent13.putExtra("1",13);
            startActivity(intent13);

            break;
        case R.id.btn14:
            Intent intent14 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dia.class);
            intent14.putExtra("1",14);
            startActivity(intent14);

            break;

    }
}
```

}

y este el xml de la activity mencionada :                                                                                                                                                                                                                            v

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Semanav1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorCelesteclaro"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backanw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/abc_vector_test" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:text="CASTIDAD Y PUREZA"
                android:textColor="#FFFEFE"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/defv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="22.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_prin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                    android:text=" example "
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:text="Días :"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-black" />

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/btncm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/mas"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/mas"
                    app:backgroundTint="#F6F3F3"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/btncmn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/menos"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/menos"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="3"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="4"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="6"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="7"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="8"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="9"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="11"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="12"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="13"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="14"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Y no se te muestra el botón que marcaste al cerrar y abrir la app?

Comment: Me imagino que deseas estos botones permanezcan de este color aun cerrando y abriendo el app?¡

Comment: si jorgesys es lo que quisiera

Comment: Podrías hacer lo que quieres con [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences), la cual te permitirá guardar el estado de los botones, en pares clave/valor (la clave puede ser el nombre o índice del botón y el valor un booleano `true` o `false`). La información es persistente (se guarda un pequeño archivo en el dispositivo y puedes leerlo/actualizarlo cuando quieras). Por ejemplo, cuando el botón 1 sea presionado guardarías algo así: `btn1 : true` y la próxima vez que quieras verificar lees en tu archivo de preferencias.

Comment: muchas gracias @A.Cedano lo voy a intentar